# How would I access this JSON data in Dart for a flutter project?

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

This is the JSON data and I'm trying to access the date and the open value with this code but I'm getting errors. What would the proper syntax be?

```
factory Stock.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) { // parse the json into data we can use
    return Stock(
      date: json['Time Series (Daily)[0]'],
      open: json['Time Series (Daily[0].open'],
      high: json['Time Series (Daily[0].high'],
      low: json['Time Series (Daily[0].low'],
      close: json['Time Series (Daily[0].close'],
      volume: json['Time Series (Daily[0].volume']
    );
  }
```

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-03-26",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-03-26": {
            "1. open": "148.4000",
            "2. high": "156.6600",
            "3. low": "148.3700",
            "4. close": "155.8800",
            "5. volume": "64143669"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get json objects or values of your json data, you need to pass attributes names and manipulate the json object

```
factory Stock.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) { // parse the json into data we can use
return Stock(
  date: json['Time Series (Daily)']['2020-03-26'],
  open: json['Time Series (Daily)']['2020-03-26']['1. open'],
  ...
);
```

}

You can also convert your json to dart object with this tool : https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't know the dates, when I try json['Time Series (Daily)'][0]['1. open'] to get the first date, it comes back null.

Comment: Because it's not a list. It's a map of <String, dynamic>. You have to convert to a list like this : json['Time Series (Daily)'].values.toList()[0]['1. open']

Comment: Wow thank you so much for all this help. In the future, do you think there is a better source I could've checked before stack overflow? I couldn't find this part you helped me with on YouTube or the official docs or by searching stack overflow.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a good place to find help. However, the official documentation of Flutter and json serialisation is pretty clear https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: Yeah I think my confusion stemmed from the fact that the official documentation didn't seem to have an example with nested JSON and I didn't realize I had to convert to list form. Just trying to improve so I bet I won't be making this mistake again. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Final question. I'm trying to get just the date values (date is now a List type) via json['Time Series (Daily)'].values.toList() and then trying to do Text(snapshot.data.date[0]) but it says "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'". I also tried json['Time Series (Daily)'].toList() without the .values

Comment: It's because your date is not a value but a key. Getting the list with .values.toList() will return the values inside your date object. 
To get the value of the key, you have to do this json['Time Series (Daily)'].keys.toList()[0]

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't realize we had a .keys option. For some reason I'm still getting "Expected value of type int but got type String". I just can't see where it would be expecting an int because a Text() widget needs a String.

Comment: Proud I figured this one out on my own: the issue wasn't with this line of code, it was elsewhere in the program I was assigning a String from the map to an int value. I wish it would've told me what line the error was on because I spent a lot of time looking in the wrong place.